# LINQ to Entities is pluralizing table names actually executed in SQL Server. How can I avoid it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

this error is very strange. When I worked with LINQ to SQL in VS2008 I had no problems, but I am in VS2012 now and I found this very strange situation.

First of all, I have VS2012 in Spanish, so pluralization is set to False. But even, if pluralization is set to True, it should only affect to class names, not to queries actually executed in database.

Well... after that introduction, I tell you that I have a table in SQL Server database named "Parametro". I added the EF model to my project generating a class named "Parametro". I have added a controller that generated a ParametroDataContext class.

First error was that the context class contained a property named "Parametroes" (why was that even when I have pluralization setting not enabled?).

I refactored that property to be "Parametros".

Then, I run the following query in a controller:

```
object o = from p in ParametroContext.Parametros
           where p.par_codigo.Equals("LOGO")
           select p;
```

What a surprise was mine when I saw that the underlying query that was executed in the database was:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Parametroes] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'LOGO' = [Extent1].[par_codigo]
```

As you see, LINQ to SQL has changed the table name to "Parametroes". That made me getting stuck at this point

Who can explain me that erratic behaviour and suggest a solution?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 1):

In your `ParametroContext` class, override the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method and add this line:

```
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: I have done it, but I got the error: the model has changed since database creation. Considere possibility of using Code First migration to update database.

Comment: I found that in Database explorer of VS2012 is ParametroDataContext listed. When I expanded Tables node, I saw "Parametroes" listed but it did not allow me to rename it. When I load design view, a "create table dbo.Parametroes" command is shown in T-SQL tab. All this is a nonsense. I will not change physical table names to make VS2012 happy. I hope Microsoft has thought about the solution to this.

Comment: Are you using EF code first? or the designer? The error you are getting in your first comment is because the table already exists (with the pluralized name). If you remove the convention, then create a new database, it won't have the pluralized name.

Comment: Finally I have removed the ParametroDataContext connection and created the controller using the connection created when added EF entities. That solved the problem. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, when creating the controller, in connection dropdown list I did not create a new context but used the same connection created when created the EDMX file. That solved the problem.

Regards
Jaime